# React Native: app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac failed - wrong path - how to change?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, package

I am facing a problem right now which I haven't had before.. Somehow React/Android is using the wrong path to my MainApplication.java file..

When I am running `react-native run-android`, Reacht/Android is using this path: 
`/Users/max/Desktop/Max/Programming/<myapp>/android/app/src/main/java/com/<myapp>/MainApplication.java`

However, the actualy path should be:
`/Users/max/Desktop/Max/Programming/<myapp>/android/app/src/main/java/de/<mydomain>/<myapp>/MainApplication.java`

So, how can I change the path from **com** to **de** and add my domain as well?

All my packages and paths are set to `de.<mydomain>.<myapp>`. So, I cannot see any reason why React/Android is using the wrong file..

I have set my path to `de.<mydomain>.<myapp>` in those files:

- android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
- android/app/build.gradle
- android/app/BUCK

I appreciate any kind of help - Thank You!

Comment: what do you have set in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under `<Application android:name="">` and `<manifest package="">`?

Comment: The same.. I have set `de.<mydomain>.<myapp> `

Comment: set the manifest package to `de.<mydomain>.<myapp>` and the application name to `.MainApplication`. also try clearing the build cache using `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`.

Comment: "set the manifest package" -> Where can I do this?

Comment: in the manifest's `package` property [see documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element)

Comment: I have add it. Looks like this now: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.<mydomain>.<myapp>"
    android:name=".MainActivity">`. I have also runned `./gradlew cleanBuildCache` and `./gradlew clean` and I am still facing the same problem with the sam wrong path.. I have now created a GitHub Issue as well: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22944

Comment: looking at the error you're receiving, that file does exist but is missing the import for `BuildConfig` (line 19 of MainApplication) which is obviously different from the file you're posted, so this seems like a cache issue. make sure you clear all cache and delete the build directory.

Comment: I have done this already multiple times... sadly not fixing the issue.. I have absolutely no idea what is causing this error..